# iPad app designing: sync with Excel file

Tags: ios, ipad, excel

I'm designing a new app for iPad for a small company. This app will use Core Data to store a local database and a database of products and prices. The last database needs to be always up to date since the prices can change.

This company, has a Excel file to keep this database of prices. So they don't have a SQL db to which I can interact from my app.

One option could be to export the Excel file in CVS and put that file in their server (accessible by internet). Then my app should parse the file.

I don't like very much this idea, though.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: If that app is only designed for that company then I'd do as you say: export the CSV, upload it to the server and use it from there. Though I'd put it somewhere where you need authorization to open it. And then you could simply hard-code the authorization in the app itself.

Comment: yep, the app won't go to the App Store. It's only for the company

Comment: then I'd do the way you said. Just make sure that the authorization is needed to open that file and that the app has built-in authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of options for you:

1. Use Google Doc as the intermediary. When the pricing Excel is updated by someone, simply upload the updated Excel to Google Docs. From your iPad app, you can read the latest data via the Goole API. If the company is up for it, they can move to Google Doc altogether and just modify the online Google Spreadsheet directly.
2. Use services like StackMob as the intermediary. You will have to write a tool to sync the pricing Excel with SrackMob but you can easily access the data via StackMob's iOS SDK.

Comment: how can I retrieve data from a spreadsheet saved in google docs? Is the obj-C API this one http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/ ?

Comment: You can use Google's rest API as well with ClientLogin as the auth method: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem to you. I recently got into a project where the client wanted to import information from an Excel file into an app. I know a lot of people say, just transform it into a CSV and parse it that way, but I really didn't want the client to go through yet another step and introduce a different file format - as simple as that may be.

I also really don't like having the information in the cloud, especially Google. Privacy is something that's important to most companies and I'd doubt they'd approve of you using Google to parse the info.

In order to parse the file, I created QZXLSReader. It's a drag-and-drop solution so it's a lot easier to use. I don't think it's as feature complete, but it worked for me.

It's basically a library that can open XLS files and parse them into Obj-C classes. Once you have the classes, it's very easy to send them to Core Data or a dictionary or what have you.

I hope it helps!

Comment: can you provide us a link please?

Comment: Could you please help me.When I drag and drop the libraray,.It is showing an error as Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _unicode_decode in xlstool.o